# All possible permutations of decimal numbers (hundredths) that sum up to 1 for a given length

Tags: r, permutation, combinatorics, subset-sum, integer-partition

Consider vector `s` as follows:

```
s=seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)

> s
 [1] 0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 0.06 0.07 
0.08 0.09 .......... 0.89 0.90 0.91 0.92 0.93 0.94 0.95 0.96 0.97 0.98 0.99
```

Now given `s` and a fixed length `m`, I would like to have a matrix for **all possible permutations** of length `m` such that each row of matrix sums up to `1` (excluding the brute force approach).

For example, if `m=4` (i.e. number of columns), the desired matrix would be something like this:

```
0.01 0.01 0.01 0.97
0.02 0.01 0.01 0.96
0.03 0.01 0.01 0.95
0.04 0.01 0.01 0.94
0.05 0.01 0.01 0.93
0.06 0.01 0.01 0.92
.
.
.
0.53 0.12 0.30 0.05
.
.
.
0.96 0.02 0.01 0.01
0.97 0.01 0.01 0.01
.
.
.
0.01 0.97 0.01 0.01
.
.
.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632322/finding-all-possible-combinations-of-numbers-to-reach-a-given-sum?rq=1

Comment: Before posting my question, I had a look at this question. The point is that it's not given in R. Moreover, my question differs from the link in that defined length should be taken into account.

Comment: @m0h3n, are you looking for `combinations` or `permutations`. From the looks of it, it seems as if you are looking for 'permutations'. See [this](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~wgreen4/Math124S07/PermuCombinations.pdf).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's how to do this using recursion:

```
permsum <- function(s,m) if (m==1L) matrix(s) else do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_len(s-m+1L),function(x) unname(cbind(x,permsum(s-x,m-1L)))));
res <- permsum(100L,4L);
head(res);
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1   97
## [2,]    1    1    2   96
## [3,]    1    1    3   95
## [4,]    1    1    4   94
## [5,]    1    1    5   93
## [6,]    1    1    6   92
tail(res);
##           [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [156844,]   95    2    2    1
## [156845,]   95    3    1    1
## [156846,]   96    1    1    2
## [156847,]   96    1    2    1
## [156848,]   96    2    1    1
## [156849,]   97    1    1    1
```

You can divide by 100 to get fractions, as opposed to integers:

```
head(res)/100;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.97
## [2,] 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.96
## [3,] 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.95
## [4,] 0.01 0.01 0.04 0.94
## [5,] 0.01 0.01 0.05 0.93
## [6,] 0.01 0.01 0.06 0.92
```

---

## Explanation

First let's define the inputs:

- `s` This is the target value to which each row in the output matrix should sum.
- `m` This is number of columns to produce in the output matrix.

It is more efficient and reliable to compute the result using integer arithmetic, as opposed to floating-point arithmetic, so I designed my solution to work only with integers. Hence `s` is a scalar integer representing the target integer sum.

---

Now let's examine the sequence generated by `seq_len()` for the non-base case:

```
seq_len(s-m+1L)
```

This generates a sequence from 1 to the highest possible value that could be part of a sum to `s` with `m` columns remaining. For example, think about the case of `s=100,m=4`: the highest number we can use is 97, participating in a sum of 97+1+1+1. Each remaining column reduces the highest possible value by 1, which is why we must subtract `m` from `s` when computing the sequence length.

Each element of the generated sequence should be viewed as one possible "selection" of an addend in the summation.

---

```
do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_len(s-m+1L),function(x) ...))
```

For each of the selections, we must then recurse. We can use `lapply()` to do this.

To jump ahead, the lambda will make a single recursive call to `permsum()` and then `cbind()` the return value with the current selection. This will produce a matrix, always of the same width for this level of recursion. Hence, the `lapply()` call will return a list of matrices, all of the same width. We must then row-bind them together, which is why we must use the `do.call(rbind,...)` trick here.

---

```
unname(cbind(x,permsum(s-x,m-1L)))
```

The body of the lambda is fairly simple; we `cbind()` the current selection `x` with the return value of the recursive call, completing the summation for this submatrix. Unfortunately we must call `unname()`, otherwise each column that ends up being set from the `x` argument will have column name `x`.

The most important detail here is the choice of arguments to the recursive call. First, because the lambda argument `x` has just been selected out during the current recursive evaluation, we must subtract it from `s` to get a new summation target, which the impending recursive call will be responsible for attaining. Hence the first argument becomes `s-x`. Second, because the selection of `x` takes up one column, we must subtract 1 from `m`, so that the recursive call will have one fewer column to produce in its output matrix.

---

```
if (m==1L) matrix(s) else ...
```

Lastly, let's examine the base case. In every evaluation of the recursive function we must check if `m` has reached 1, in which case we can simply return the required sum `s` itself.

---

## Floating-point discrepancy

I looked into the discrepancy between my results and psidom's results. For example:

```
library(data.table);

bgoldst <- function(s,m) permsum(s,m)/s;
psidom <- function(ss,m) { raw <- do.call(data.table::CJ,rep(list(ss),m)); raw[rowSums(raw)==1,]; };

## helper function to sort a matrix by columns
smp <- function(m) m[do.call(order,as.data.frame(m)),];

s <- 100L; m <- 3L; ss <- seq_len(s-1L)/s;
x <- smp(bgoldst(s,m));
y <- smp(unname(as.matrix(psidom(ss,m))));
nrow(x);
## [1] 4851
nrow(y);
## [1] 4809
```

So there's a 42 row discrepancy between our two results. I decided to try to find exactly which permutations were omitted with the following line of code. Basically, it compares each element of the two matrices and prints the comparison result as a logical matrix. We can scan down the scrollback to find the first differing row. Below is the excerpted output:

```
x==do.call(rbind,c(list(y),rep(list(NA),nrow(x)-nrow(y))));
##          [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
##    [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##    [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##    [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##    [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##    [5,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##
## ... snip ...
##
##   [24,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##   [25,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##   [26,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##   [27,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##   [28,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
##   [29,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##   [30,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##   [31,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##   [32,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##   [33,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
##
## ... snip ...
```

So it's at row 29 where we have the first discrepancy. Here's a window around that row in each permutation matrix:

```
win <- 27:31;
x[win,]; y[win,];
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 0.01 0.27 0.72
## [2,] 0.01 0.28 0.71
## [3,] 0.01 0.29 0.70 (missing from y)
## [4,] 0.01 0.30 0.69 (missing from y)
## [5,] 0.01 0.31 0.68
##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 0.01 0.27 0.72
## [2,] 0.01 0.28 0.71
## [3,] 0.01 0.31 0.68
## [4,] 0.01 0.32 0.67
## [5,] 0.01 0.33 0.66
```

Interestingly, the missing permutations normally do sum to exactly 1 when you compute the sum manually. At first I thought it was data.table's `CJ()` function that was doing something strange with floats, but further testing seems to indicate it's something `rowSums()` is doing:

```
0.01+0.29+0.70==1;
## [1] TRUE
ss[1L]+ss[29L]+ss[70L]==1;
## [1] TRUE
rowSums(CJ(0.01,0.29,0.70))==1; ## looks like CJ()'s fault, but wait...
## [1] FALSE
cj <- CJ(0.01,0.29,0.70);
cj$V1+cj$V2+cj$V3==1; ## not CJ()'s fault
## [1] TRUE
rowSums(matrix(c(0.01,0.29,0.70),1L,byrow=T))==1; ## rowSums()'s fault
## [1] FALSE
```

We can work around this `rowSums()` quirk by applying a manual (and somewhat arbitrary) tolerance in the floating-point comparison. To do this we need to take the absolute difference and then perform a less-than comparison against the tolerance:

```
abs(rowSums(CJ(0.01,0.29,0.70))-1)<1e-10;
## [1] TRUE
```

Hence:

```
psidom2 <- function(ss,m) { raw <- do.call(data.table::CJ,rep(list(ss),m)); raw[abs(rowSums(raw)-1)<1e-10,]; };
y <- smp(unname(as.matrix(psidom2(ss,m))));
nrow(y);
## [1] 4851
identical(x,y);
## [1] TRUE
```

---

## Combinations

Thanks to Joseph Wood for pointing out that this is really *permutations*. I originally named my function `combsum()`, but I renamed it to `permsum()` to reflect this revelation. And, as Joseph suggested, it is possible to modify the algorithm to produce combinations, which can be done as follows, now living up to the name `combsum()`:

```
combsum <- function(s,m,l=s) if (m==1L) matrix(s) else do.call(rbind,lapply(seq((s+m-1L)%/%m,min(l,s-m+1L)),function(x) unname(cbind(x,combsum(s-x,m-1L,x)))));
res <- combsum(100L,4L);
head(res);
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]   25   25   25   25
## [2,]   26   25   25   24
## [3,]   26   26   24   24
## [4,]   26   26   25   23
## [5,]   26   26   26   22
## [6,]   27   25   24   24
tail(res);
##         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [7148,]   94    3    2    1
## [7149,]   94    4    1    1
## [7150,]   95    2    2    1
## [7151,]   95    3    1    1
## [7152,]   96    2    1    1
## [7153,]   97    1    1    1
```

This required 3 changes.

First, I added a new parameter `l`, which stands for "limit". Basically, in order to guarantee that each recursion generates a unique combination, I enforce that each selection must be *less than or equal to* any previous selection in the current combination. This required taking the current upper limit as a parameter `l`. On the top-level call `l` can just be defaulted to `s`, which is actually too high anyway for cases where `m>1`, but that's not a problem, since it's just one of two upper limits that will be applied during sequence generation.

The second change was of course to pass the latest selection `x` as the argument to `l` when making the recursive call in the `lapply()` lambda.

The final change is the trickiest. The selection sequence must now be computed as follows:

```
seq((s+m-1L)%/%m,min(l,s-m+1L))
```

The lower limit had to be raised from the 1 used in `permsum()` to the lowest possible selection that would still allow a descending-magnitude combination. The lowest possible selection of course depends on how many columns have yet to be produced; the more columns, the more "room" we have to leave for future selections. The formula is to take an integer division of `s` on `m`, but we also must effectively "round up", which is why I add `m-1L` prior to taking the division. I also considered doing a floating-point division and then calling `as.integer(ceiling(...))`, but I think the all-integer approach is much better.

For example, consider the case of `s=10,m=3`. To produce a sum of 10 with 3 columns remaining, we cannot make a selection less than 4, because then we would not have enough quantity to produce 10 without ascending along the combination. In this case, the formula divides 12 by 3 to give 4.

The upper limit can be computed from the same formula used in `permsum()`, except that we must also apply the current limit `l` using a call to `min()`.

---

I've verified that my new `combsum()` behaves identically to Joseph's `IntegerPartitionsOfLength()` function for many random test cases with the following code:

```
## helper function to sort a matrix within each row and then by columns
smc <- function(m) smp(t(apply(m,1L,sort)));

## test loop
for (i in seq_len(1000L)) {
    repeat {
        s <- sample(1:100,1L);
        m <- sample(2:5,1L);
        if (s>=m) break;
    };
    x <- combsum(s,m);
    y <- IntegerPartitionsOfLength(s,m);
    cat(paste0(s,',',m,'\n'));
    if (!identical(smc(x),smc(y))) stop('bad.');
};
```

---

## Benchmarking

Common self-contained test code:

```
library(microbenchmark);
library(data.table);
library(partitions);
library(gtools);

permsum <- function(s,m) if (m==1L) matrix(s) else do.call(rbind,lapply(seq_len(s-m+1L),function(x) unname(cbind(x,permsum(s-x,m-1L)))));
combsum <- function(s,m,l=s) if (m==1L) matrix(s) else do.call(rbind,lapply(seq((s+m-1L)%/%m,min(l,s-m+1L)),function(x) unname(cbind(x,combsum(s-x,m-1L,x)))));
IntegerPartitionsOfLength <- function(n, Lim, combsOnly = TRUE) { a <- 0L:n; k <- 2L; a[2L] <- n; MyParts <- vector("list", length=P(n)); count <- 0L; while (!(k==1L) && k <= Lim + 1L) { x <- a[k-1L]+1L; y <- a[k]-1L; k <- k-1L; while (x<=y && k <= Lim) {a[k] <- x; y <- y-x; k <- k+1L}; a[k] <- x+y; if (k==Lim) { count <- count+1L; MyParts[[count]] <- a[1L:k]; }; }; MyParts <- MyParts[1:count]; if (combsOnly) {do.call(rbind, MyParts)} else {MyParts}; };
GetDecimalReps <- function(s,m) { myPerms <- permutations(m,m); lim <- nrow(myPerms); intParts <- IntegerPartitionsOfLength(s,m,FALSE); do.call(rbind, lapply(intParts, function(x) { unique(t(sapply(1L:lim, function(y) x[myPerms[y, ]]))); })); };

smp <- function(m) m[do.call(order,as.data.frame(m)),];
smc <- function(m) smp(t(apply(m,1L,sort)));

bgoldst.perm <- function(s,m) permsum(s,m)/s;
psidom2 <- function(ss,m) { raw <- do.call(data.table::CJ,rep(list(ss),m)); raw[abs(rowSums(raw)-1)<1e-10,]; };
joseph.perm <- function(s,m) GetDecimalReps(s,m)/s;

bgoldst.comb <- function(s,m) combsum(s,m)/s;
joseph.comb <- function(s,m) IntegerPartitionsOfLength(s,m)/s;
```

---

**Permutations**

```
## small scale
s <- 10L; m <- 3L; ss <- seq_len(s-1L)/s;
ex <- smp(bgoldst.perm(s,m));
identical(ex,smp(unname(as.matrix(psidom2(ss,m)))));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,smp(joseph.perm(s,m)));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst.perm(s,m),psidom2(ss,m),joseph.perm(s,m));
## Unit: microseconds
##                expr      min        lq      mean   median        uq      max neval
##  bgoldst.perm(s, m)  347.254  389.5920  469.1011  420.383  478.7575 1869.697   100
##      psidom2(ss, m)  702.206  830.5015 1007.5111  907.265 1038.3405 2618.089   100
##   joseph.perm(s, m) 1225.225 1392.8640 1722.0070 1506.833 1860.0745 4411.234   100
```

---

```
## large scale
s <- 100L; m <- 4L; ss <- seq_len(s-1L)/s;
ex <- smp(bgoldst.perm(s,m));
identical(ex,smp(unname(as.matrix(psidom2(ss,m)))));
## [1] TRUE
identical(ex,smp(joseph.perm(s,m)));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst.perm(s,m),psidom2(ss,m),joseph.perm(s,m),times=5L);
## Unit: seconds
##                expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##  bgoldst.perm(s, m) 1.286856  1.304177  1.426376  1.374411  1.399850  1.766585     5
##      psidom2(ss, m) 6.673545  7.046951  7.416161  7.115375  7.629177  8.615757     5
##   joseph.perm(s, m) 5.299452 10.499891 13.769363 12.680607 15.107748 25.259117     5
```

---

```
## very large scale
s <- 100L; m <- 5L; ss <- seq_len(s-1L)/s;
ex <- smp(bgoldst.perm(s,m));
identical(ex,smp(unname(as.matrix(psidom2(ss,m)))));
## Error: cannot allocate vector of size 70.9 Gb
identical(ex,smp(joseph.perm(s,m)));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst.perm(s,m),joseph.perm(s,m),times=1L);
## Unit: seconds
##                expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  bgoldst.perm(s, m) 28.58359 28.58359 28.58359 28.58359 28.58359 28.58359     1
##   joseph.perm(s, m) 50.51965 50.51965 50.51965 50.51965 50.51965 50.51965     1
```

---

**Combinations**

```
## small-scale
s <- 10L; m <- 3L;
ex <- smc(bgoldst.comb(s,m));
identical(ex,smc(joseph.comb(s,m)));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst.comb(s,m),joseph.comb(s,m));
## Unit: microseconds
##                expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
##  bgoldst.comb(s, m) 161.225 179.6145 205.0898 187.3120 199.5005 1310.328   100
##   joseph.comb(s, m) 172.344 191.8025 204.5681 197.7895 205.2735  437.489   100
```

---

```
## large-scale
s <- 100L; m <- 4L;
ex <- smc(bgoldst.comb(s,m));
identical(ex,smc(joseph.comb(s,m)));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst.comb(s,m),joseph.comb(s,m),times=5L);
## Unit: milliseconds
##                expr       min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval
##  bgoldst.comb(s, m)  409.0708  485.9739  556.4792  591.4774  627.419  668.4548     5
##   joseph.comb(s, m) 2164.2134 3315.0138 3317.9725 3540.6240 3713.732 3856.2793     5
```

---

```
## very large scale
s <- 100L; m <- 6L;
ex <- smc(bgoldst.comb(s,m));
identical(ex,smc(joseph.comb(s,m)));
## [1] TRUE

microbenchmark(bgoldst.comb(s,m),joseph.comb(s,m),times=1L);
## Unit: seconds
##                expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
##  bgoldst.comb(s, m)  2.498588  2.498588  2.498588  2.498588  2.498588  2.498588     1
##   joseph.comb(s, m) 12.344261 12.344261 12.344261 12.344261 12.344261 12.344261     1
```

Comment: that is quite the one-liner.  Upvoted but would be better with some comments

Comment: As always, it is very difficult to explain how a recursive function works.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I'm wondering, for `m=3`, why @Psidom's solution returns `4845` rows while that of yours has `4851` rows.

Comment: It's probably due to the `==` and float number inaccuracy. I would trust @bgoldst's answer more than mine since he is using integer instead of numeric type.

Comment: @bgoldst, very nice answer.  I bet you could alter this to provide `combinations` only much, much faster. +1!

Answer (score 3):

Take `m=4` for example, a memory intensive approach would be:

```
raw <- data.table::CJ(s,s,s,s)
result <- raw[rowSums(raw) == 1, ]    
head(result)

     V1   V2   V3   V4
1: 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.97
2: 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.96
3: 0.01 0.01 0.03 0.95
4: 0.01 0.01 0.04 0.94
5: 0.01 0.01 0.05 0.93
6: 0.01 0.01 0.06 0.92
```

Comment: This is actually a brute force approach. if `m=3`, `nrow(raw)` would be `970299` while `nrow(result)` would be `4845`. The difference is significant. For `m>4`, computing the `raw` table would become infiseable.

Comment: I agree. It is very memory intensive. And my suggestion is  try to write a recursive function to solve the problem.

Comment: @Psidom, nice approach. I'm always learning new ways to apply `data.table`.

Comment: Voted up for your effort and, more importantly, for revealing a situation in which `rowSums()` function fails.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an algorithm that will return pure `combinations` (order doesn't matter). It is based off of an integer partition algorithm built by Jerome Kelleher ([link](http://jeromekelleher.net/generating-integer-partitions.html)).

```
library(partitions)
IntegerPartitionsOfLength <- function(n, Lim, combsOnly = TRUE) {
    a <- 0L:n
    k <- 2L
    a[2L] <- n
    MyParts <- vector("list", length=P(n))
    count <- 0L
    while (!(k==1L) && k <= Lim + 1L) {
        x <- a[k-1L]+1L
        y <- a[k]-1L
        k <- k-1L
        while (x<=y && k <= Lim) {a[k] <- x; y <- y-x; k <- k+1L}
        a[k] <- x+y
        if (k==Lim) {
            count <- count+1L
            MyParts[[count]] <- a[1L:k]
        }
    }
    MyParts <- MyParts[1:count]
    if (combsOnly) {do.call(rbind, MyParts)} else {MyParts}
}

system.time(res <- combsum(100L,5L))
 user  system elapsed 
 0.75    0.00    0.77

system.time(a <- IntegerPartitionsOfLength(100, 5))
 user  system elapsed 
 1.36    0.37    1.76

identical(smc(a),smc(res))
[1] TRUE

head(a)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1   96
[2,]    1    1    1    2   95
[3,]    1    1    1    3   94
[4,]    1    1    1    4   93
[5,]    1    1    1    5   92
[6,]    1    1    1    6   91
```

A really large example (N.B. using the `smc` function created by @bgoldst):

```
system.time(a <- IntegerPartitionsOfLength(100L,6L))
 user  system elapsed 
 4.57    0.36    4.93

system.time(res <- combsum(100L,6L))
 user  system elapsed 
 3.69    0.00    3.71

identical(smc(a),smc(res))
[1] TRUE

## this would take a very long time with GetDecimalReps below
```

Note: `IntegerPartitionsOfLength` only returns the `combinations` of a particular set of numbers and not the `permutations` of a set of numbers (order matters). E.g. for the set `s = (1, 1, 3)`, the combinations of `s` is precisely `s`, while the permutations of `s` are: `(1, 1, 3), (1, 3, 1), (3, 1, 1)`.

If you want an answer like the OP is asking for, you will have to do something like this (this is by no means the best way and isn't nearly as efficient as @bgoldst's `permsum` above):

```
library(gtools)
GetDecimalReps <- function(n) {
    myPerms <- permutations(n,n); lim <- nrow(myPerms)
    intParts <- IntegerPartitionsOfLength(100,n,FALSE)
    do.call(rbind, lapply(intParts, function(x) {
        unique(t(sapply(1L:lim, function(y) x[myPerms[y, ]])))
    }))
}

system.time(a <- GetDecimalReps(4L))
 user  system elapsed 
 2.85    0.42    3.28

system.time(res <- combsum(100L,4L))
 user  system elapsed 
 1.35    0.00    1.34

head(a/100)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.97
[2,] 0.01 0.01 0.97 0.01
[3,] 0.01 0.97 0.01 0.01
[4,] 0.97 0.01 0.01 0.01
[5,] 0.01 0.01 0.02 0.96
[6,] 0.01 0.01 0.96 0.02

tail(a/100)
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[156844,] 0.25 0.26 0.24 0.25
[156845,] 0.25 0.26 0.25 0.24
[156846,] 0.26 0.24 0.25 0.25
[156847,] 0.26 0.25 0.24 0.25
[156848,] 0.26 0.25 0.25 0.24
[156849,] 0.25 0.25 0.25 0.25

identical(smp(a),smp(res))  ## using the smp function created by @bgoldst
[1] TRUE
```

@bgoldst algorithms above are superior for both return types (i.e. combinations/permutations). Also see @bgoldst's excellent benchmarks above. As a closing remark, you can easily modify `IntegerPartionsOfLength` to obtain all combinations of `1:100` that sum to `100` for `k <= m` by simply changing the `k==Lim` to `k <= Lim` and also setting `combsOnly = FALSE` in order to return a list. Cheers!

Comment: thanks but your function is doing wrong. take `nrow` of `res` and `a`. You will notice why this is the case.

Comment: @m0h3n, reread my answer again.  I'm aware that `a` (combinations) and `res` (permutations) aren't the same. See the link I posted above in the comments to your question.

Comment: By the way, your solution does not do what the question is asked for. Re-read the question and accepted answer.

Comment: @m0h3n, I had a copy/paste error (Sorry about that). It should work now. By the way, I know the solution provided by bgoldst is far superior, I was simply showing the community a different way of thinking about the problem. [Integer Partition Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) is an incredibly rich topic that doesn't get enough attention. Anywho, this was an incredibly fun problem, and as always, cheers!!

Comment: Your results are wrong in both cases (i.e.`res` IS NOT EQUAL `a`). It's also funny you benchmark two algorithms that are NOT doing the same job.

Comment: @JosephWood I appreciate your answer and comments. I've heavily edited my answer based on your insights. Unfortunately, since I used the name `combsum()` for my original permutation function, I've probably caused a lot of confusion. And even moreso because in my edited answer I renamed it to `permsum()` and then wrote a new `combsum()` to generate combinations. So please make note of my changes, and sorry for the confusion. Upvoted your answer.

Comment: @bgoldst, I will update as soon as possible. Your algorithms are truly amazing!!!

Comment: @m0h3n, `res` and `a` are the same (they were ordered differently)

Comment: With the UPDATED `combsum` function from the accepted answer, yes. Now they generate identical results. Before, you compared your results with `permsum` which your output was wrong and, as such, was much faster ;)

Comment: Btw, I'm now convinced to vote up your answer and I did, indeed.